# Отслеживание редиректов

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, redirect

Всем привет, в общем, я на локальной машине развернул сайт, с небольшими бубнами все заработало, но, остались какие-то редиректы на "блоге", при переходе на страницу блога, идет редирект на рабочий сайт, блог на ВП, хтаццесс чистил, бд тоже чистил, вп конфиг правил, редиректы как происходили так и происходят, есть у кого-то идеи, как можно отследить откуда они берутся?

Для наглядности путь:

Захожу по адресу --> локальная-машина/blog --> на выходе получаю --> боевой-хостинг/blog

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте.

Если чистили базу и правили конфиг, то посмотрите может плагин какой-нибудь установлен для редиректа.

Может редирект прописан в functions.php.
Поищите в папке с сайтом адрес боевого хостинга. Вдруг он прописан в каком-нибудь самописном плагине.

Либо через phpmyadmin поищите упоминание боевого хостинга в базе данных.
Вот как искать в phpmyadmin - https://joomla-support.ru/thread/5121/

Answer (score 0):

> я на локальной машине развернул сайт, с небольшими бубнами все
>   заработало,

Надо было использовать бубен правильной системы. А именно - плагины для мигарции.  Напр https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/.

Редиректы - это видимая часть проблемы. Это говорит о том, что не везде адреса заменились.  А ведь ещё есть пути к файлам, которые остались неправильные. А самое главное - побиты сериализованные массивы настроек как самого ВП, так и плагинов и темы. Если сразу что-то и не видно, то потом может аукнуться, но разобраться в причинах "глюков" и неработоспособности элементов может быть сложно.
В общем используй плагины для мирграции.